# PHP (Regex) - Match url part with parenthesis

Tags: php, regex

I am pretty new to regex (only really started looking seriously to it a few hours ago) and even if it is not going that bad... I am having a bad time matching parenthesis.

Here's what I have / want:

```
$p = "#(\/new_arrivals\/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+|\/\(offset\)\/([0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9]))$# i";
$s = "http://www.example.com/abc/cba/new_arrivals/(offset)/29";
```

I would like to match `/(offset)/29` ... but I can't seem to be able to make it match the parenthesis even if I did try to escape them.

Also.. the number 29... starts into 29 and goes up till 500. Is there any simpler way to make it match 2 or 3 numbers instead all of this `([0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9])`?

Comment: To answer your last part, try `[0-9]{2,3}`. Or, `\d{2,3}`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex:

```
\/\(offset\)\/\d{2,3}
```

Demo:http://regex101.com/r/tZ7zS4

Comment: `/` doesn't need to be escaped if not used as pattern delimiter (op uses `#`).

Comment: @lafor I don't know php. Can you explain a bit more on this?

Answer (score 0):

`\/\(*[A-z]+\)*\/[0-9]+$`

matches: /(offset)/29

`\/[A-z]+\/[0-9]+$`

matches: /offset/29

Hope it helps